# Definition of property RD

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, geometric-group-theory

In the following paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2001458?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents Jolissaint introduces the property RD of a group G if the space $H_L^\infty(G)$ is contained in the reduced $C^*$-algebra of $G$ for some length function $L$ (where $H_L^\infty(G)$ are the functions on $\psi$ G such that the $L^2$ norm of $\psi(1+L)^s$ is bounded for every $s\in \mathbb{R}$) Then he claims that this happens **if and only if** for every $\phi$ in the group algebra of $G$ the following inequality holds for some $s,c,L$
$$||\phi||\leq c||\phi||_{2,s,L}$$
where the norm $||.||$ is the reduced norm and the norm $||.||_{2,s,L}$ is the $L^2$ norm of $\phi(1+L)^s$.

I don't see why this should hold the group algebra is the same as the compactly supported functions over $G$ which is dense in both $H_L^\infty(G)$ (Well this is not really a Banach space but I mean dense in each $H_L^s(G)$) and $C^*_r(G)$ and the equation between the norms just seems to say that there is a surjection from $H_L^s(G)\rightarrow C^*_r(G)$ for some $s$ and not an inclusion as asked for. Jolissaint appeals to the closed graph theorem but I don't understand where it comes from as you're applying it to the group algebra which is not a Banach space in those norms. Could anyone please explain what is meant here?

Basically I guess if you have the norm bound every cauchy sequence in $H_L^s$ is cauchy in $C_r^*$ and hence you can define a map from $H_L^s\rightarrow C_r^*$ but why is this map injective when seen from $H_L^\infty$

Moreover in the opposite direction I am not sure why an inclusion of $H^\infty_L(G)\rightarrow C_r^*$ will imply such a norm bound.

Comment: maybe MO is a better place for this. Recommended tags there: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, maybe geometric-group-theory too (even if it's quite analytic).

Comment: Four your last question: You have to use the definition of the (inverse limit) topology for $H^\infty_L$ if i understood correctly.

Comment: I realised you might aswell just be able to do this due to the characterisation of boundedness and continuity in Locally convex spaces. Since you have an embedding it is a linear operator and hence by theory of Locally convex spaces it is a bounded map and hence it is bounded by a supremum of finitely many of those norms and hence by one of those norms.

Comment: And I'm thinking that the injectivity of the map from $H^s_L \rightarrow C^*_r$ might follow from the injectivity of the left regular representation.

Comment: For your first question: $H_L^s$ is defined as a subset of $L^2$, so in order to prove injectivity it is enough to notice that the norm of the reduced norm controls that of $\ell^2(G)$.

Comment: that works, thank you @AdriánGonzález-Pérez